# Why does fmt.Println inside a goroutine not print a line?

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "irc.freenode.net:6667")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    go func() {
        str, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            // handle it
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(str)
    }()

}
```

If I don't have the code that reads from the  buffer in a goroutine, it outputs a message like this, which is what I expect to happen:

```
:zelazny.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
```

However, having it inside a goroutine prints nothing.

Can someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your program will exit when the `main()` function finishes.  This is likely to happen before your goroutine has time to run and print its output.

One option would be to have the main goroutine block reading from a channel, and have the goroutine write to the channel when it has completed its work.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, James. I definitely think channels are what I am looking for.

Answer (score 44):

Another common way to "wait for a goroutines end", is using `WaitGroup`: 
http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup . You can use `waitGroup.Add(1)` for each started goroutine, then use `waitGroup.Done()` in each goroutine after it finishes. In the main function you can use `waitGroup.Wait()` and this will wait until `waitGroup.Done()` has been called for each added goroutine.

Answer (score 5):

Write data to a channel `ch` at the end of goroutine and read data from `ch` out of goroutine can make the main function waiting for goroutine print message.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"

func main() {
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "irc.freenode.net:6667")

reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
ch := make(chan byte, 1)
go func() {
    str, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        // handle it
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
    ch <- 1
  }()
  <-ch
}
```

Answer (score -12):

You need to add a time delay like `time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)` (this waits 3 seconds).

The goroutine closes when the program terminates. I had the exact same problem.