# Synchronisation of threads in Go lang

Tags: multithreading, go

I want to understand a bit more about how synchronisation of threads works in go. Below here I've have a functioning version of my program which uses a done channel for syncronization.

```
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func Goroutine1(i_chan chan int, done chan bool) {
    for x := 0; x < 1000000; x++ {
        i := <-i_chan
        i++
        i_chan <- i
    }
    done <- true
}
func Goroutine2(i_chan chan int, done chan bool) {
    for x := 0; x < 1000000; x++ {
        i := <-i_chan
        i--
        i_chan <- i
    }
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    i_chan := make(chan int, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 2)
    i_chan <- 0

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    go Goroutine1(i_chan, done)
    go Goroutine2(i_chan)
    <-done
    <-done
    Printf("This is the value of i:%d\n", <-i_chan)
}
```

However when I try to run it with out any synchronisation. Using a wait statement and no channel to specify when it's done so no synchronisation.

```
const MAX = 1000000

func Goroutine1(i_chan chan int) {
    for x := 0; x < MAX-23; x++ {
        i := <-i_chan
        i++
        i_chan <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    i_chan := make(chan int, 1)
    i_chan <- 0
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    go Goroutine1(i_chan)
    go Goroutine2(i_chan)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    Printf("This is the value of i:%d\n", <-i_chan)
}
```

It'll print out the wrong value of i. If you extend the wait for let say 1 sec it'll finish and print out the correct statement. I kind of understand that it has something with both thread not being finished before you print what's on the `i_chan` I'm just a bit curious about how this works.

Comment: Are you missing a call to `Goroutine2` in your first example?  Where's the definition of `Goroutine2` in your second example?  You mentioned something about a "wait statement" in your second example -- what's a "wait statement" and where is it?

Comment: Note: Go doesn't have "threads" as a language construct. Do you mean "goroutines"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does fmt.Println inside a goroutine not print a line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228887/why-does-fmt-println-inside-a-goroutine-not-print-a-line)

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency goroutines are how I understood it green threads so you would write the keyword go and go starts up a new green thread. Correct?

Comment: @Amit Kumar Gupta. Yeah some copy pasta error right there. I did fix it now. By wait statement it's the sleep statement in the end. So basically it does not really wait for anything to finish it just put the main thread to sleep.

Comment: I got my answer down bellow if anyone is interested.

@Volker yeah it's in the same area/ basically the same problem as the main thread finishes before the two other threads are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your [first example would deadlock, since it never calls `GoRoutine2`](http://play.golang.org/p/WTplbTQx1G) (the OP since edited the question).
If [it calls `GoRoutine2`, then the expected `i` value is indeed 0](http://play.golang.org/p/tRVqx9g4he).

Without synchronization, (as [in this example](http://play.golang.org/p/5w9mxsQgvj)), there is no guarantee that the main() doesn't exit *before* the completion of `Goroutine1()` and `Goroutine2()`.
For a 1000000 loop, a 1 millisecond wait seems enough, but again, no guarantee.

```
func main() {
    i_chan := make(chan int, 1)
    i_chan <- 0
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    go Goroutine2(i_chan)
    go Goroutine1(i_chan)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    Printf("This is the value of i:%d\n", <-i_chan)
}
```

see more at "[How to Wait for All Goroutines to Finish Executing Before Continuing](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/)", where the canonical way is to use the [sync package’s `WaitGroup` structure](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), as in [this runnable example](http://runnable.com/UwEzO6LcUjMdAABH/using-sync-waitgroup-to-slurp-json-from-reddit-concurrently-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-before-continuing-).