# Multiple go routines consuming from a channel causing loss of data

Tags: go, goroutine

I am a newbie to Go. In my example below, multiple go routines are consuming from an unbuffered channel.

Code :

```
var c = make(chan int)

func f() {
    for val := range c {    
        fmt.Printf("routine 1 : %v\n", val)
    }
}   

func g() {
    fmt.Printf("routine 2 : %v\n", <-c)
}

func main() {
    go f()
    go g()
    c <- 0
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4
    c <- 5
    close(c) 
}
```

The output was :

```
routine 1 : 0
routine 1 : 2
routine 2 : 1
routine 1 : 3
routine 1 : 4
```

Value 5 is missing from this and never gets printed ! Why is this happening? If I remove the call -  `go g()`, it works perfectly.

Also, if I make the channel buffered, say :

```
var c = make(chan int, 10)
```

There is no output at all. I understand that for unbuffered channel, the send completes after receive completes, which is not the case for buffered. Still, for buffered case, if channel has not yet sent any int, wouldn't the for loop be blocked considering it a nil channel?

Please help out with both my queries. Appreciate all the inputs.

Comment: It is not missing, you just did not have time to consume it: the program exited by that moment. Also: https://play.golang.org/p/6fKTsbMncK

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228887/why-does-fmt-println-inside-a-goroutine-not-print-a-line

Answer (score 6):

As soon as `5` is consumed, the program exits. There's no time for it to print the output.  If you run the program enough times, you may find that on some occasions, it does happen to print the output before it closes, but it'll be purely random.

You need to add some mechanism to wait for your channels to finish, before exiting the program.

Answer (score 2):

What @Flimzy mentions is correct, after the read is over the send unblocks and the main go routine exits after closing the channel even before the print could complete (sometimes it may complete so you may see it once in a while). Once the main go routine exits, so do all other go routines. Here's a solution which uses `WaitGroup` for synchronization https://play.golang.org/p/i2uHw3X1G3 - with this you should not see any missouts. Hope this helps.

For buffered channel, the main go routine doesn't have to wait for the read to complete after writing the values, so it just exits after it sends all the values. So again, you need to use synchronization for this.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to wait for goroutines to finish**:

---

method 1: using `sync.WaitGroup`:

> ```
> // A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish.
> // The main goroutine calls Add to set the number of
> // goroutines to wait for. Then each of the goroutines
> // runs and calls Done when finished. At the same time,
> // Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.
> ```

try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/0giDGiwGdk):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var c = make(chan int)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func f() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for val := range c {
        fmt.Printf("routine 1 : %v\n", val)
    }
}

func g() {
    defer wg.Done()
    if data, ok := <-c; ok {
        fmt.Println("routine 2 :", data)
    }
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(2)
    defer wg.Wait()
    go f()
    go g()
    c <- 0
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4
    c <- 5
    close(c)
}
```

sample output:

```
routine 2 : 0
routine 1 : 1
routine 1 : 2
routine 1 : 3
routine 1 : 4
routine 1 : 5
```

---

method 2: using quit channel, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/rNhxHx--1h):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    go f()
    go g()
    c <- 0
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4
    c <- 5
    close(c)
    <-quit
    <-quit
}
func f() {
    defer done()
    for val := range c {
        fmt.Printf("routine 1 : %v\n", val)
    }
}
func g() {
    defer done()
    if data, ok := <-c; ok {
        fmt.Println("routine 2 :", data)
    }
}
func done() {
    quit <- struct{}{}
}

var c = make(chan int)
var quit = make(chan struct{}, 2)
```

output:

```
routine 2 : 0
routine 1 : 1
routine 1 : 2
routine 1 : 3
routine 1 : 4
routine 1 : 5
```

Comment: @Mayank: I hope this helps.

Comment: This code seems incorrect, it can still exit without printing since the `wg.Wait` will be waiting for only atmost two go routine executions (may be more than 2 values, bcos in one of the routines it can read multiple values), to complete (instead of the 5).

Comment: @Ravi using `sync.WaitGroup` is the idiomatic way. here there are only two extra goroutines to wait not 5!

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment, but your code is incorrect. Let's understand: suppose the goroutine g gets executed only after goroutine f has consumed all the values sent. Finally the `wg.Wait` will still be waiting, till `wg.Done` in g gets executed. Now the channel read in g will receive a 0 value (since channel is closed, but this value was never sent!) & incorrectly print it out. Here's your code with an added sleep to (g) to simulate: https://play.golang.org/p/L98ZNhV-XA . To compare added a sleep (to g) in the code I shared earlier - same input as yours : https://play.golang.org/p/MXV7_pDAye

Comment: The guideline is simple - keep N in `wg.Add(N)` always equal to the number of jobs you are generating and never the number of go routines or threads, you may be creating to handle them! Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad you changed your comment and also improved your code to check if the channel is closed in g, now add a small fix to check if ok is true/false & print based on that - it'll finally be correct. Always better to keep things clean and simple - that is idiomatic Go! And we never know which code gets into production, we mostly have professionals from the real field here, so we must take care on what we post!

Comment: @Ravi  / @ A.R - Thank you for the detailed explanation and outlining the proper solution. Helped a lot :)